# Remove temporary file after returning in raw format in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, filestream

I have a WCF service which works in raw format, using streams:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEncryptingService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/")]
    [OperationContract]
    Stream SignDocument(Stream requestStream);
}

public class EncryptingService : IEncryptingService
{
    public Stream SignDocument(Stream requestStream)
    {
        string originalFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string signedFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var originalFileStream = File.Open(originalFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            requestStream.CopyTo(originalFileStream);
        }

        XmlDocumentSigner.SignFile(originalFileName, signedFileName);

        return File.Open(signedFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    }
}
```

Now, how can I remove this file after WCF ends returning the file?

I have tried to use `finally` block, but it gets called right after `return`, and throws exception, since the file is still used by a process.

Of course, these is a workaround like a background worker waiting for a file to be available for deletion, but, in my opinion, it is not like how web-services should be implemented.

Comment: Can't you avoid using files in the first place? Just using (in memory) streams instead?

Comment: @Christian.K Unfortunately, `XmlDocumentSigner` is a wrapper around an external unmanaged DLL library which uses very specific algoritms (no managed or not file-based alternative libraries) and can only sign files :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution came to mind inexcusably quickly, and it is absolutely logical: I can simply read file contents to memory and remove the file.

```
public Stream SignDocument(Stream requestStream)
{
    string originalFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    string signedFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (var originalFileStream = File.Open(originalFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        requestStream.CopyTo(originalFileStream);
    }

    XmlDocumentSigner.SignFile(originalFileName, signedFileName);

    byte[] signedFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(signedFileName);
    File.Delete(signedFileName);
    return new MemoryStream(signedFileBytes);
}
```

Note that `using` statement makes this code fail as well:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(signedFileBytes))
{
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, well done in finding your answer. Yours was also the less complicated version!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks :)

Comment: See here also: https://devdump.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/disposing-return-values/. They talk about disposing, but you can subscribe to OperationCompleted and delete your file there. It's better than copying whole file to memory.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but you could open the file and write that stream to another stream. Something like:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(signedFileName))
{
    //Read from fs and write to ms
}
```

Then all you will need to do is call delete on the file and return `ms`:

```
File.Delete(signedFileName);
return ms;
```